# Writing JUnit for a method with Builder Pattern

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a method with structure something like this :

```
  public Results stepToWait(Arguments arguments, State state, Info info) throws Exception {

    return createWorkObj(arguments).runStep(
        contextBuilder().stepName("WAIT_CREATION").state(state)
            .stepFailureMessage("Failure while waiting")
            .maxDuration(Duration.ofHours(1))
            .maxRetryAttempts(2)
            .initialRetryDelay(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
            .build(),

        (State state) -> {

            // throwing this exception will call this method again (internal functionality)

            // if(1==1){
            //     throw new Exception("Test Exception");
            // }


            try {
                // Do some work here
            } catch (ABCException ex) {
                return same-step-goes-here ;
            }

            return next-step-goes-here ;
        });
}
```

So , I want to create a test of a scenario where if we uncomment the commented exception , in that case the method goes for a retry , I want to test and print different values of initialRetryDelay used inside builder pattern above .

It would be a big help to know how to break a method down step by step to test it for a particular scenario .

Thanks.

Please let me know if any clarification is required .

**EDIT :**

As earlier I had too many questions and now I understand I don't need to mock everything , I am gonna focus on one question , how to test the method changing value of builder argument `initialRetryDelay` to different values and print it .

Comment: I would assign Builder result to a local variable. What is `contextBuilder()` exactly doing? Do you need any injected members for your Builder? Why do you eant to mock your Builder?

Comment: What are the builder is doing with the state argument?

Comment: Rather than "breaking a method down" you may find that you want to break your class up into simpler classes to make it more testable. At present the parts you can mock are the parameters to `stepToWait`. Your tests will also be testing the rest of your class, i.e. `createWorkObj` and `contextBuilder`. If there's a reason not to test the implementation of these methods (e.g. they do I/O) then you might want to inject instances of classes which implement those methods, so that they can be easily mocked.

Comment: @tgdavies I can do that , just inject the instances of classes implementing createWorkObj and contextBuilder . Ok .

Comment: @MichaelKatt I do not necessarily want to mock the builder , just was wondering how to test the scenario , so maybe I can do the test without mocking it ?

Comment: @devcodes I should also have mentioned that you can mock any constructor parameters your class has. But yes, I'd try to test it as is, mocking only parameters, and see whether you run in to any problems.

Comment: @devcodes Rather than asking how to write a test involving `initialRetryDelay`, I think you should try to write such a test, and then ask a new question if you run into problems, showing us the code you have written and the specific problem that you have.

Comment: @tgdavies sure , I think so too , getting lot's of "how to"s on my mind , will try to clear it one at a time

Comment: @tgdavies I'm gonna first start by looking how to make this method throw an exception from a junit test , so it will retry (method will call itself again) , I am not able to achieve that only first .

Answer (score 0):

1. have a look at [Baeldung.com - Mockito and Fluent APIs](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-fluent-apis) where they tell you to mock a builder using fluent api.
2. I would assign the result of `contextBuilder` to a local variable. By this way you could easier overlook runStep().

Comment: thanks , I will check , I edited the question focusing on only the scenario rather than mocking of whole pattern whihc might be unnecessary